# MongoDB remove GridFS objects from shell

Tags: javascript, shell, mongodb, gridfs

I have files stored in a MongoDB using GridFS. I need to remove some of those files by ID, from the JavaScript shell. I need to remove a single file using it's ID. I figured I could just do this:

```
db.fs.files.remove({_id: my_id});
```

This works to some extent; it removes the file from the `fs.files` collection but does not remove the chunks itself from the `fs.chunks` collection. The reason I know that is because I check the length of both collections before and after in RockMongo.

I could go through the chunks and remove those that are referring to that file, but is there a better, built-in way of doing that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want to use `db.fs.delete(_id);` instead.

**Update**
Sorry, that apparently doesn't work from the shell, only through the driver. GridFS is a specification for storage implemented by the drivers. Looks like it doesn't have much built-in functionality from the shell, as such.

**Update 2** There is also a command line tool, mongofiles (http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/GridFS+Tools), which allows you to delete files **by name**. `mongofiles delete <filename>`. It comes with a warning that it will delete all of the files by that name, so it's not as granular as by id.

Comment: Ah I see. Sadly, I can't use mongofiles because I only have the ID of the file I want to delete. Do you foresee any problems I would get by deleting the matching chunks myself?

Comment: Do you need to do this through the shell? Why not connect with a driver in your language of choice? And no, as far as I know it would be ok to do something like `db.fs.chunks.remove({files_id:my_id});` and then `db.fs.files.remove({_id:my_id});`

Comment: I would have preferred doing it from the shell but I'll use a language with a driver. Thanks!

Answer (score 26):

You can delete gridFS file by deleting both chunks and files from shell. for example

```
db['fs.chunks'].remove({files_id:my_id});
db['fs.files'].remove({_id:my_id});
```

Those commands will do such trick.

Answer (score 3):

```
mongofiles --host localhost:30000 --db logo delete logo_susan1225.png
```

refer to this page:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongofiles/#bin.mongofiles